# Node + MongoDB(Mongoose) + Passport - I can log in to any account with any password

Tags: node.js, mongodb, passport.js

I currently have a login system written in Node + MongoDB(Mongoose) + Passport . However, as long as I provide a valid username, I can log in with any password. This is the method I have for password checking:

```
UserSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(password) {
    if (!this.password) { return false; }
    return bcrypt.compareSync( password, this.password );
};
```

And this is my passport LocalStrategy check:

```
if (user && user.comparePassword(password)) {
    // User and password both match, login success
    console.log(currentTime + " - USER_LOG_IN_SUCCESS: '" + username + "' LOGGED IN");
    return done(null, user);
} else {
    // Wrong password
    console.log(currentTime + " - USER_LOG_IN_ERROR: '" + username + "' ENTERED INVALID PASSWORD");
    return done( null, false,
         req.flash("loginError", "The password is invalid."));
}
```

Comment: I would print out `password`, `this.password`, and the result of the bcrypt in your `comparePassword` function to debug.